# How to change the price in checkout page in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to change the price in checkout page in magento2.
I'm getting the price from API and i just want to replace the final price from that API in checkout page.
In Catalog and Product detail page, the price has been changed as per the API request. But during checkout, price is coming from database, instead of api price.
I tried using some observer events but its not working fine.
It would be very helpful if anybody give suggestion on this.

Comment: have you tried `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event? and it will be helpful if you provide code of what you have done. Welcome to Magento community.

Comment: Refer this once http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/